# Spring boot : Prometheus query to get Number of Major garbage collections per min in last 10 mins

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a requirement to get Number of Major garbage collections per min in last 10 mins, and if that number exceed 2, I need to generate alert manager alert.
Based on online search, I think I need to use "jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count" in prometheus query, but not sure about exact syntax. Can someone please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what "Number of Major garbage collections per min in last 10 mins" means? Do you want an alert if there where 2 GCs in 10 minutes, 2 GCs in 1 minute or something else?